# my check box is not selected any box in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox

*** here is html code for checkbox am using checkbox for dynamic value initiazation from databases but checkbox are not selecting any value***

```
                <div  class="widget-body" style="display: block;">
                        <div class="widget-main">
                                <div class="table-responsive">
                                <table class="table">

                                <thead>
                                <tr>
                                <th>item</th>
                                <th>received</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>

                    <tbody ng-repeat="emp in nodueaccountassets">      
        <tr>
<td>{{emp}}</td>  <td> <input type="checkbox"  ng-model="emp.selected" value="{{emp.name}}"/></td>

                             </tr>
                        </tbody>
                     </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

***and js controller code is***

```
     angular.forEach($scope.nodueaccountassets,function(emp){
        if (emp.selected) $scope.albumNameArray.push(emp.name);

          alert(emp.selected);
```

Comment: Where does the angular.forEach get run? Please, post its context...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you want to get the selected employees, you can do this,

```js
 var app = angular.module("app", []);

 app.controller("listController", ["$scope",
   function($scope) {
     $scope.albumNameArray = [];
     $scope.nodueaccountassets = [{
       "name": "Raymond",
       "age": 28,
       "selected": false
     }, {
       "name": "Bruce",
       "age": 96,
       "selected": false
     }, {
       "name": "Laura",
       "age": 62,
       "selected": false
     }];
     $scope.getSelected = function() {
       angular.forEach($scope.nodueaccountassets, function(emp) {
         if (emp.selected) 
         $scope.albumNameArray.push(emp.name);
       })
     }

   }

 ]);
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.4/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div ng-controller="listController">
    <div class="widget-main">
      <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>item</th>
              <th>received</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody ng-repeat="emp in nodueaccountassets">
            <tr>
              <td>{{emp}}</td>
              <td>
                <input type="checkbox" ng-model="emp.selected" value="{{emp.name}}" />
              </td>

            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>

    <button ng-click="getSelected()">Get Selected</button>
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat=" opt in albumNameArray">
        {{ opt }}
      </li>
    </ul>

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: my nodueaccountassets value is coming from data base and when i trying select checkbox its not selecting

Comment: how does it come?

Answer (score 0):

possibly the value you are getting from server for emp.selected in string format instead of booleans you are getting value like "true",

check if you are getting response like this if so you need to convert selected object to boolean.

```
[{
 name: 'sushil',
 selected: "true"
}]
```

Comment: you r right my values coming in string format like this :$scope.nodueaccountassets=data.list;  but i want bind with checkbox is any way to make sense in html  <td>{{emp}}</td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox"  ng-model="emp.selected"  value="{{emp.name}}"/></td>